# Get Tornado Websocket to run render()

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, tornado

Using Websockets, I am trying to re-render a page everytime the server pings to it, this is the error I keep getting:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 781, in render
self.finish(html)
RuntimeError: Method not supported for Web Sockets
```

Is there any sort of way to get around this? is there any way i can call `render` without calling `finish()` at the end?

Answer (score 1):

The method isn't supported because `render` writes it as an HTTP response, which you can't do once you've converted the connection from HTTP to WebSockets. The closest equivalent is `self.write_message(self.render_string('foo.html'))`, with javascript code in the browser to receive those messages and replace the contents of the page.